# How to link with a shared library installed in a custom directory by another yocto bitbake recipe

Tags: linker, yocto, bitbake

I have two bitbake recipes `a.bb` and `b.bb`

The recipe `a.bb` installs a shared library `libABC.so` in a custom path `/opt/app/lib`.

The recipe `b.bb` generates a binary that needs to link with the `libABC.so`. I am not able to achieve this.

- `a.bb`:

```
do_install(){
  install -d ${D}/opt/app/lib
  install -m 0644 {WORKDIR}/dir/libABC.so ${D}/opt/app/lib
}
```

- `b.bb`:

```
DEPENDS += "a"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "a"
```

However, the compiler always complains about the missing library:

`arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: cannot find -lABC`

If I install the `libABC.so` in the standard path `${libdir}`, the same binary links successfully.

I have tried to use the `SYSROOT_DIRS` in `a.bb` which at least shows `./recipe-sysroot/opt/app/lib/libABC.so` in the logs of `b.bb` but it still doesn't work.

```
SYSROOT_DIRS += "/opt/app/lib"
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try to also extend `BUILD_LDFLAGS` variable with something like `BUILD_LDFLAGS += "-L${STAGING_DIR}/opt/app/lib"` or similar, so it will consider this folder also when looking for libraries. Note that the `STAGING_DIR` variable is a semi-lazy guess from me, I would have to check if it is really what I mean... maybe you will have to correct that.

Comment: @skandigraun This suggestion is not working. I have tried to add BUILD_LDFLAGS += "-L${STAGING_DIR}/opt/app/lib" in the recipe a.bb because I don't wish to mention the path in the b.bb. The intention is to resolve the dependencies by using DEPENDS or similar mechanism.

Comment: What? Why did you add it to a.bb? You are installing a.bb to a custom location. You have to specify this custom location in b.bb, so that it can find what to link. You need to either install a.bb to a regular location, like `${D}/${libdir}` or you have to inform b.bb somehow where the magic is located.

Comment: @skandigraun I understand your point. I just wanted to clarify if my approach to write in the a.bb file is ok or not. By the way, it had not worked even if I tried to write in the b.bb file. I didn't mention in my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to fix your `a:do_install`:

```
do_install(){
  install -d ${D}/opt/app/lib
  install -m 0644 {WORKDIR} ${D}/opt/app/lib
           ^
           |
           (What is this ? Did you mean libABC.so ?)
}
```

Now, let me explain something about recipes dependencies in Yocto:

Have in mind that `DEPENDS += "a"` in bitbake means, exactly, the following:

Hey `bitbake`:

1. Go build `a` first until you reach `do_populate_sysroot` which prepares `/path/to/tmp/work/../a/0.1-r0/sysroot-destdir`
2. Go prepare `recipe-sysroot` of `b` with what is inside `sysroot-destdir` of `a` using `b:do_prepare_sysroot` task that is executed before `do_configure`.

*[IMPORTANT NOTE]*

If you are installing something under `/opt` that is itself a compile-time dependency of another recipe, in your case `a`, then you need to do not forget that `/opt` by default is not in `SYSROOT_DIRS` which is the variable that contains what to copy from recipe `a` to recipe `b`'s `recipe-sysroot` folder, so make sure to add this to `a.bb`:

```bash
SYSROOT_DIRS:prepend = "/opt "
```

You already did this, so good.

Now, `recipe-sysroot` is the root file system of the recipe `b`, so the linker `ld` will check libraries under `recipe-sysroot`, you can check this with:

```bash
bitbake -e b | grep "^export LD="
```

You will find something like:

```bash
export LD="x86_64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/path/to/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/b/0.1-r0/recipe-sysroot  "
```

You can notice under the `recipe-sysroot` that there is no `etc/ld.conf.d` and other `ld`-configuration-related stuff, so we expect that the linker `ld` has some information to look under `recipe-sysroot/{usr/lib,lib}`. Don't worry, the linker knows everything based on `LDFLAGS`.

Now, you need to understand that there are multiple `LDFLAGS`:

- `BUILD_LDFLAGS`: This is used for native building for the HOST
- `TARGET_LDFLAGS`: This is used for target builds for your machine
- `BUILDSDK_LDFLAGS`: When building for an SDK

So, you need to change `TARGET_LDFLAGS` in your `b.bb` recipe.

Now, you also need to know what variable points to `/path/to/b/recipe-sysroot`, that is `RECIPE_SYSROOT` variable, so add:

```bash
TARGET_LDFLAGS:prepend = "-L${RECIPE_SYSROOT}/opt/app/lib "
```

Comment: Hi Talel BELHADJSALEM, Thank you for the suggestion. I would try and update.

Comment: This solution works fine. Marked it as the accepted answer. Thanks for the help.